# Соседний блок применяет правила соседнего блока

Tags: html, css, margin

Есть два блока. С одинаковыми классами. Одному из них задал дополнительный класс, чтобы стилизовать его, при нажатии на кнопку, но это не суть. Соседний блок применяет свойство `height`, если я задаю только классу `.seventh_block_active`. Но и `.seventh_block` тоже принимает это свойство.

Почему так? Причем `background` принял только `.seventh_block_active`, а `height` `.seventh_block` принимает..

```css
.seventh_block_list:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: '\f00c';
 color: #6fc754;
 margin-right: 7px;
}
.seventh_block_title {
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.seventh_block_price {
 border: 1px solid #d4d4d5;
 border-radius: 30px;
 padding: 5px 17px;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.seventh_block_text {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #8c8f94;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.seventh_block {
 background: #ebebed;
 padding: 60px 40px;
}
.seventh_block_list {
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.seventh_block_btn {
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
 width: 210px;
 border-radius: 40px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid #267df4;
}
.seventh_block_btn {
 margin-top: 50px;
 color: #267df4;
}
.seventh_block_btn_margin {
 margin-top: 99px;
}
.seventh_block {
 border-radius: 15px;
}
.seventh_block_active {
 background: #fff;
}
.seventh_block {
 margin-top: 178px;
 margin-left: 1px;
}
.seventh_blocks {
 padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="seventh_blocks text-center d-flex">
    <div class="seventh_block seventh_block_active">
        <h3 class="seventh_block_title">Starter</h3>
        <span class="seventh_block_price">Free</span>
        <p class="seventh_block_text">Build your schedule<br> every day</p>
        <div class="seventh_block_list">Unlimeted events</div>
        <div class="seventh_block_list">Connect Dropbox & Evernote</div>
        <button class="seventh_block_btn seventh_block_btn_margin">Get started</button>
    </div>
    <div class="seventh_block">
        <h3 class="seventh_block_title">Pro</h3>
        <span class="seventh_block_price">$4.99</span>
        <p class="seventh_block_text">Make your life<br>
        better</p>
        <div class="seventh_block_list">Unlimeted events</div>
        <div class="seventh_block_list">Connect Dropbox & Evernote</div>
        <div class="seventh_block_list">Personal Assistant</div>
        <button class="seventh_block_btn">Make me a Pro</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы если добавляете код, то убедитесь, что он работает и может нормально отобразить вашу проблему.

Comment: Спасибо, учту..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У блока `seventh_blocks` есть свойство `display: flex` (класс `d-flex`), а это значит что для блоков `seventh_block` устанавливается дефолтное свойство `align-items: normal`, которое в текущей ситуации ведет себя как `stretch` и подстраивает все дочерние елементы под размер родителя. И когда вы меняете высоту одному из потомков, меняется высота и родителя, что приводит к увеличению остальных потомков.